# scanf Input output confusion

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

*I was confused about my assumption as to how the while loop might work ..
I've tried it on my computer, and seen that all cases have been as expected,
am i right, or am i missing out on something ?*

```
 while(scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c) ,a||b||c ) { /* some code */ }
```

**This means that even if one value (either a,b or c )  is non zero , it will loop on**

---

```
while(scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c) ,a&&b&&c ) {  /* some code */ }
```

**This means whenever any of a, b or c  becomes zero, the loop terminates**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, the first loop will go on until all three values turn zero, while the second loop will stop as soon as one of three items becomes zero.

This is because [*comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) discards the result of the first expression - essentially, the expression `a || b || c` or `a && b && c` become your loop condition.

Note that your loops may not terminated when the input ends prior to reading a stopping combination (all zeros / one zero). When this happens, your loop becomes infinite. To prevent this from happening, change your loops to

```
 while(scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c) == 3 && (a||b||c) ) { //some code }
```

or

```
 while(scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c) == 3 && a && b && c) ) { //some code }
```

Comment: The wiki link really helped , and your explanation was spot on !! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {//some code}  // loop will run
while(false) {//some code} // loop will not run
```

since any value other than `0` is considered as true so your first `while` loop will execute until all of them become `0`.
and in second `while` loop if any of them become `0` the loop will not execute.
just basic operators.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since `while(true)` will never become `false` and vice versa. `True` and `false` are constants, while `a`, `b` and `c` are variables.